# Kernel dying when executing to_crs to convert geometry of geodataframe

Tags: jupyter-notebook, geopandas, fiona

When I try to convert the geometry of a geodataframe from EPSG4326 to EPSG3857 in Jupyter Notebook running Python 3, my kernel keeps dying.

Minimal reproducible code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
     'Country': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})

crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, crs=crs, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))

gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.to_crs(epsg=3857)
```

I have tried the solution in [this closed Github issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1113) - i.e. updating to latest version of PyProj. This does not solve the problem for me.

I have also tried creating a new, dedicated conda environment for geopandas. This does not solve the problem for me, either.

When I run the minimal reproducible code in a python terminal script, I get the following output which points to an issue with Fiona.

```
(geo) RichardgrimsMBP:desktop data_science$ python tocrs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tocrs.py", line 4, in
import geopandas as gpd
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/init.py", line 7, in
from geopandas.io.file import _read_file as read_file # noqa
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py", line 7, in
import fiona
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/init.py", line 86, in
from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 11, in
from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _CCCryptorGCMFinalize
Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/libtiledb.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in /opt/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/libtiledb.dylib
```

Comment: Does the issue exist if you run this without jupyter in a python terminal?

Comment: When your environment is active, what is the value for the environment variable PROJ_NETWORK?

Comment: Works for me on Windows with `conda create -n test36_12_cforge -c conda-forge python=3.6.12 ipython geopandas` environment. Could you try your minimal example in ipython in that environment? Does the kernel die with an error or just disappear?

Comment: @snowman2 - when i run the minimal example in a python terminal I get an ImportError at the 'import geopandas as gpd' line: ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _CCCryptorGCMFinalize
  Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/libtiledb.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /opt/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/libtiledb.dylib

Comment: @doctorG - creating that environment doesn't work for me. See terminal output below.

(geo) RichardgrimsMBP:desktop data_science$ conda create -n test36_12_cforge -c conda-forge python=3.6.12 ipython geopandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.

Comment: Did anything funky happen when you installed anaconda on your Mac? Can you, for example, run `conda update -n base conda`? Or does that have issues?

Comment: @doctorG - that runs into inconsistency issues. "The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully"

Comment: @doctorG - i reinstalled conda. I am now able to run `conda update -n base conda` without a problem. However, my original problem still persists. It seems to be a problem with the conda solver, as per this Github issue: https://github.com/conda-forge/fiona-feedstock/issues/172

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the problem by pinning an older version of tiledb (2.0.8) in my conda environment. It seems there's an issue with the conda solver disregarding my macOS version (10.11.6) and giving me a version of tiledb (2.1.2) that is not compatible.

See github issues [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/fiona-feedstock/issues/172) and [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10334).